# How to run Spring boot cron job at different time interval when same code is deployed on 2 diff servers who are started and running at same time?

Tags: spring-boot, cron, spring-boot-actuator

We are going to deploy same code on two different servers which will be started and running at the same time but the problem is both servers will be started at the same time will run cron job at the same time, then the cron job process will run by 2 servers which will be duplicated. So I want to start cron job on both servers should start at a different initial time so that 1 server can read some rows from DB and finish its task and change the status of the same row which is processed, so that other server can read only new entries.

Comment: You can configure the cron expression via the application properties and you can override the property when launching the application via the command line argument.

Comment: Thanks @MohamedSanaulla. we are not deploying the application through the command line because we are using Kubernetes, Bamboo, Docker and other stuff so code will be deployed on both servers as per plan. 

I was trying to use initialDelay property of cron in spring-boot where I can generate a random number (Ex. from 1 to 1000) so that we can achieve running 2 cron on separate servers would run at a different time interval, But its giving me compile time error saying "The value for annotation attribute Scheduled.initialDelay must be a constant expression"

Comment: You can export an environment variable in Dockerfile using `ENV <VariableName>=<Value>`. This <Value> can be passed while creating docker container `docker build --build-arg <VariableName>=<Value>`. 
This way the envrionment variable can be an initial delay or a cron expression and can be injected into the corresponding class using `@Value`

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla If we do this(@Value) same value will be assigned in both server so both servers will have the same value and starting cron at the same time, So there will be no effect of doing this. I guess we need to do something else out of the box. What you say?

Comment: While building the docker images you can pass different values to the variable name.

Comment: I will try this. Thanks @MohamedSanaulla